# Drush cim command causing PHP fatal error on windows machine

Tags: php, drupal-8, drush

When running `drush cim/cr` commands in a Drupal 8 (core 8.5.5) project i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in E:\Work\EmakinaCH\IheidCH\web\modules\contrib\search_api_solr\src\Plugin\search_api\backend\SearchApiSolrBackend.php on line 2669
 [error]  Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
Error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in E:\Work\EmakinaCH\IheidCH\web\modules\contrib\search_api_solr\src\Plugin\search_api\backend\SearchApiSolrBackend.php, line 2669
```

And here's the aforementioned line of code

```
  protected function flattenKeys($keys, array $fields = [], string $parse_mode_id = 'phrase') {
```

This error only occurs on one test machine which is running Win10 + Wamp 64-bit version 3.1.0, regardless of which php version is run on it 5.6, 7.0 or 7.1.9. On any other linux machine i use there are no issues.

Anyone know how to fix this, or what is the cause of this error?
Thanks

Comment: few links for you to check https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api/issues/101 https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2546

Comment: @lakshman Thanks for your input, unfortunately they resolved their issue with a php version change, i already tried several php versions 7.0, 7.1, 7.1.9 and none of them worked :(

Comment: drush config-import ...try a full use not alias & say

Comment: I think that this is more of a app configuration issue. If this only happens on one server, I'd recommend comparing the configs.